# Unable to access samba file share after mounting on Mac

Tags: macos, bash, mount, samba

I am trying to automate mounting, copying a file to a samba shared folder and then unmounting the drive from my Mac. I wrote a simple bash script to do it

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Mounting Drive"

mkdir /Volumes/foo

mount -t smbfs //'domain;user':password@server/foo /Volumes/foo

echo "Copying"

#these 2 commands fail even though it works if I execute them in the terminal
ls /Volumes/foo
cp something.txt /Volumes/foo/something.txt

echo "Unmounting Drive"

umount /Volumes/foo
```

I get the error from `ls` or `cp`: `No such file or directory`

Why do these commands work when I enter them into the Terminal serially but not as a bash script?
What can I do to make this script work?

Comment: run only the `mkdir` and `mount` from the script, then from a terminal try the `ls` and post results. I am quite sure, this will fail also.

Comment: It works.. I see the file list of `/Volumes/foo`. I am also able to to use Finder to navigate to the folder..